# AWS S3 403 server error due to backup file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, backup, boto, http-status-code-403

Using boto for file upload, I've had a strange 403 Forbidden error, as many other users.
None of the solutions provided to them worked for me.

The thing is, I uploaded many files on my bucket, and most of them did work, until one gave a 403 error.

I further realised that the problem was comming from a file named UUID_Server.csv~

When renaming the file, removing the tilde, everything works.
I made a workaround in my script but the solution isn't really elegant.

Any idea why a '~'  wouldn't be digest for s3 ?
I don't use any config file, everything is in the script. My python version is 2.7.3 and boto is up to date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS S3 shall be fine with `~` in file name.

Using AWSCLI `aws` command I was able to upload file named `data.txt~`.

Anyway, you talk about `boto` being up to date. If you check README.rst of this project, you will find there:

```
boto 2.39.0

Released: 9-Apr-2015
```

It is a year and 2 days today without an update.

Number of issues in this package is growing and according to Mitch Garnaat (author of `boto`) [comment to my issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3306#issuecomment-132625810) **"There is no way home"**, the future development is only with `boto3`.

So my advice is: try to **rewrite the script to `boto3`**, it is likely to work better and shall stay working longer.

Comment: Since `~` is a character that can require special handling in a URL via url-encoding (or may be given special handling when it isn't required) and the signing code must generate a signature that matches the encoding, this seems like a likely candidate for an explanation of the problem, and the deprecated state of boto... well, yeah. It should have worked. +1

Comment: I switched to boto3 with (almost) the exact same script. And it worked fine this time, thanks !

Comment: @Sogeking Visiting `boto` page I have found [pull request dealing with your problem](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/98651e86a5fddee84c123ff78dbe09eca68b5d5a) merged a week ago into master. I wonder if they ever release new version or will keep `boto` in "use development version if you like" status as they do now. Good you switched to `boto3`.